# strikethrough a paragraph in a doc using interop in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have searched a word in a paragraph and if that word is found in any of the paragraph then i need to strikethrough the paragraph.Till now i have tried

```
 Public Function StrikethroughPara(ByVal searchstring As String) As Boolean
    Dim Content As String

    For b As Integer = 1 To objword.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count - 1
        Content = objword.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(b).Range.Text
        Try

            If Regex.IsMatch(Content, searchstring) Then


                **objword.Selection.Font.StrikeThrough = 9999998**//This is not working
                'objword.Selection.Paragraphs.Style.StrikeThrough = WdConstants.wdToggle
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next

End Function
```

Please Provide me the solution if possible.

Comment: Did you try to get the range of the paragraph and then setting the Font.StrikeThrough property like this?
int undefinedInt = (int)Word.WdConstants.wdUndefined;
objword.Selection.Paragraphs.range.Font.StrikeThrough = undefinedInt;

Comment: HI thanks for your reply,i have tried this but it shows the error that range is not a member of microsoft.office.interop.Paragraph.It's the compile time error.If u have any solution for this plz response.

Comment: I worked in some vsto project more than a year ago and I almost forgot about all this. I just tested the following code and it is working fine for me. Could you please give it a try?
   objword.Selection.Paragraphs[1].Range.Font.StrikeThrough = (int)WdConstants.wdForward;

Comment: Hi thank god that it hasn't any compile time error now,But in runtime it's throwing a com exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  ErrorCode=-2146822347
  HelpLink="wdmain11.chm#25421"
  Message="The requested member of the collection does not exist."
  Source="Microsoft Word"
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs.get_Item(Int32 Index)
       at CommonCodeLibrary.ClsWinWord.StrikethroughPara(String searchstring).I am trying to resolve this if you know then can suggest.Thanks For your valuable response.bye

Comment: Hi Tariqulazam ,Thanks for your precious suggession.It helped me a lot i just modified like this:-objword.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(b).Range.Font.StrikeThrough = WdConstants.wdToggle.Thanks again

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Could you please accept as a solution?